# I'm new here. Where to look for documentation for my specific board

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

sorry if this isn't the done thing. I have a little red space invader shaped board that has an arduino chip on the back from a conference. There is an LCD display and I've just got it to function correctly (there was a power issue.

```
ATE1 E
0
ATE
1
```

The above is what the screen is displaying and I can't make heads or tails of it. Any ideas?

I've tagged this with arduino-micro because I think it may be that although I've had relative success using 'SparkFunProMicro' board in arduino IDE

**EDIT:** I've been able to get some more board info from arduino IDE. VID:1B4F, PID:9204, BN:unknown board, SN:Upload a sketch to get it.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, but I'm guessing Iding the boards is the first step.  Maybe a photo of the board would help.  Sparkfun boards are normally red and they use the Vendor ID of 1B4F.  They make a 5v Pro Micro with a Product ID of 9205 and a 3.3V version PID=9203.  They also make a Leonardo with a PID of 9206.  So you PID is in the right area, but god knows what it is.  Can you read the back of the ICs to see what they say?

Comment: Quote from [Tech Note Wiki](http://wiki.bauwe.nl/Arduino/ProMicro): All SparkFun ATmega32U4 boards share the same VID - 0x1B4F, and they all have unique PIDs. 5V Pro Micros lay claim to PIDs 0x9205 and 0x9206 (one for the bootloader, one for the sketch). 3.3V Pro Micros will show up as 0x9203 and 0x9204 for bootloader and sketch, respectively. And the Fio v3 has 0xF100 and 0xF101.

Comment: `an arduino chip on the back` - what chip? Part number?